# Bookmark with a link to open the attachments pane

Tags: hyperref, pdf, links, bookmarks

Is it possible to have a **bookmark with a link to open the attachments pane**?
If you carefully read **hyperref** packege you'll see that the **\Acrobatmenu** alows you to have links that enables you to open and show a lot of menus and options in Adobe Acrobat.
But I don't see any attachments pane option.

Is it possible? Is there any workaround or way to achieve this?

I've also looked with **javascript** but I can't find any info regarding this :(

From [this excelent site](https://www.tug.org/applications/hyperref/ftp/doc/manual.html) you can see the available options for \Acrobatmenu:

[image]

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Officially the PDF format ([specification](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html)) only supports four named actions:
`NextPage`, `PrevPage`, `FirstPage`, `LastPage`.

It depends on the PDF viewer, which other non-standard actions might be supported.

The [JavaScript API reference](https://wwwimages2.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/js_api_reference.pdf) lists names in the description of method `execMenuItem` of object `app`. There the name **`ShowHideFileAttachment`** can be found. It does open the attachment tab, if it was closed, and closes it, if it was opened.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{embedfile}
\embedfile{\jobname.tex}
% \hypersetup{pdfpagemode=UseAttachments}
\begin{document}
\Acrobatmenu{ShowHideFileAttachment}{Show/hide file attachments}
\bookmark[ 
  named=ShowHideFileAttachment,
]{Show/hide file attachments}  
\end{document}
```

---

An alternative to open the attachment tab is the `PageMode` setting that is only used, when the document is opened:

```
\hypersetup{pdfpagemode=UseAttachments}
```

Combinations with other tabs (bookmarks/thumbs/...) are not defined in the PDF specification.

Comment: It is not possible to use a `\Acrobatmenu` 'button' from your `hyperref` package then to open/close the Attachment pane?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: It's pretty much the same. I have added it to the example.

Comment: I have to praise you Heiko!!
You always have the (correct) answer! Amazing!
You truly are the PDF guru!

That worked like a charm!